# Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: <a/> Jquery UI

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, user-interface, autocomplete

i tried to build an autocomplete search. Therefore i used the jquery ui and this little snippet of code:

```js
$(function() {
 
    $("#search").autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
            $.ajax(
            {
                url: 'autocomplete.php',
                dataType: "json",
                data:
                {
                    term: request.term,
                },
                success: function (data)
                {
                    response(data);
                },
                error: function (err) {
                    console.log("AJAX error in request: " +   JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 2,
        select: function(event, ui) {
            var url = ui.item.id;
            if(url != '#') {
                location.href = '/blog/' + url;
            }
        },
        html: true,
        open: function(event, ui) {
            alert("open");
            $(".ui-autocomplete").css("z-index", 1000);
        }
    });
 
});
```

The file autocomplete.php returns json encoded data.

My Problem is, that for every valid response and result i get a "Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: " error and my results aren't displayed in a list. What does that error mean?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: try look in console , its shows error line.

Comment: does data returned match expected data format as per UI docs?

Comment: Change the <a/> to </a>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
   /*here comes your code*/
});
```

Also, in your success function, try to change it to

```
success: function (data)
            {
                alert(data.d);
            },
```

because you are returning the **d**, not **data**. d represents a property of **data** object.

Answer (score 0):

You did not give all information to identify the problem, but you should call

```
console.log(data);
```

at the start of your `success` function and look at the response in your console. You must have used the bad syntax of `<a/>` instead of `</a>` either in your PHP generating your request response or in the function you pass as `response`.